# throw statement in switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement, throw

I try to run a code, but I cannot understand what throw statement do in this part, I thought that we can use ´throw´ statement in try-catch block.
any can help me with this example:

```
switch(npt) {
  case 1: {
    a = NPoint1;
    b = NLine1;
    break;
  }
  .
  .
  .
  case 5: {
    a = NPoint2;
    b = NLine2;
    break;
  }
  default:
    printf("what you entered is wrong");
    throw 1;
  };
  return 1;
}
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I dont know what the operation of throw is in default section....

Comment: You need to read up on [exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throw` is catched by the nearest `try-catch` block. If it's not in your own code, it's in the code that invoked your's and so on up the stack.